# Any free online service which keeps track of all the passwords automatically?

Tags: webapp-rec, security, passwords

I don't want to enter the password to a site to keep the record. I want a service which automatically catches the passwords and stores it.

Comment: Are you sure you want your passwords stored in the cloud?

Comment: I agree with Alex - you should really consider the security implications of keeping your passwords with an online service. If that one service has a security breach, you've just had a personal security breach for every site you visit.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, there is [1password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword), which isn't free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [lastpass.com](http://lastpass.com) - I have no connection to them other than as a satisfied user.

Comment: As a lastpass user myself, +1. However, bear in mind that LastPass isn't completely automatic. You will still need to press a few buttons - but once the site is stored, it's a breeze to use. I moved from Xmarks to this.

Comment: I am another very satisfied LastPass user.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Xmarks](http://xmarks.com) as well, manages bookmarks/passwords/tabs across browsers/computers/web

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind being limited to a browser, consider [Firefox Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868/) (Firefox 4 (now in Beta 4) includes Firefox Sync by default) - a cloud-based service that syncs not only your passwords, but also history, bookmarks and your entire session across PCs.

Answer (score 1):

For those, who afraid of giving their password to a thirdparty: try out [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) and sync it with the cloud anyhow (like dropbox, google drive, skydrive...). There are some [tools](http://keepass.info/plugins.html) to integrate it with your browser.

Comment: Anyone who downvoted: would you mind sharing your concerns why is it a bad answer?